# Fix duplicate rows while selecting nested fields from BigQuery using JOIN and UNNEST

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to copy data from one BQ table to another and having trouble with un-nesting and JOINs. I have two fields of `REPEATED RECORD` type in my schema and when I try to JOIN those, I get a lot of duplicate rows. Here´s my query:

```
SELECT
  Title as Title,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Address.Field1, Address.Field2)) AS Address,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Work.Field1, Work.Field2)) AS Work
  
FROM
   source_table
   LEFT JOIN UNNEST(Address) AS Address,
   LEFT JOIN UNNEST(Work) AS Work

GROUP BY
  Title
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
| Title | Address.Field1|Address.Field2| Work.Field1|Work.Field2|
|-------|---------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
| A     |     aaa       |     ccc      |     eee    |     ggg   |
|       |     bbb       |     ddd      |     fff    |     hhh   |
```

But when I `JOIN` `Address` and `Work`, I get a log of duplicate rows like this:

```
| Title | Address.Field1|Address.Field2| Work.Field1|Work.Field2|
|-------|---------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
| A     |     aaa       |     ccc      |     eee    |     ggg   |
|       |     aaa       |     ccc      |     fff    |     hhh   |
|       |     aaa       |     ccc      |     eee    |     ggg   |
|       |     bbb       |     ddd      |     fff    |     hhh   |
```

I need help with fixing the JOINS and would appreciate some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subqueries:

```
SELECT
  Title as Title,
  ARRAY(select STRUCT(Field1, Field2) from UNNEST(source_table.Address)) AS Address,
  ARRAY(select STRUCT(Field1, Field2) from UNNEST(source_table.Work)) AS Work
FROM
   source_table
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sergey. What if I have another nested Record inside `Address` such as `Address.Another_Address.Field1`. How can I map that?

Comment: Try `ARRAY(select STRUCT(Another_Address.Field1) from UNNEST(source_table.Address)) AS Address, UNNEST(Address.Another_Address) as Another_Address`

Comment: I get the error: `Expected end of input but got keyword UNNEST ` at `UNNEST(Address.Another_Address)`. Could the parentheses for `ARRAY` be misplaced?

Comment: Oh, looks like I misplaced the bracket: `ARRAY(select STRUCT(Another_Address.Field1) from UNNEST(source_table.Address) AS Address, UNNEST(Address.Another_Address) as Another_Address)`